# How to generate directive which has templateRef as Input

Tags: angular

I have below directive which has an input; how can I write its spec file:

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTest]'
})
export class TestDirective {

  constructor(public tpl: TemplateRef<any>) {
  }

}
```

I tried below one but it is giving me an error:

```
import { TestDirective } from './test.directive';
    describe('TestDirective', () => {
      it('should create an instance', () => {
        const directive = new TestDirective();
        expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

Error **new TestDirective();** This is giving me error as default input is needed.

I tried below `<h1>test</h1>` but is not working, I am getting:

```
'<h1>test</h1>' is not assinable to TemplateRef<any>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directive doesn't have input. It **injects** TemplateRef. That means you can only use it like that:

```html
<ng-template appTest>
  Some content of the template
</ng-template>
```

If you want a directive with template as input, you need to write it like that:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTest]'
})
export class TestDirective {
  @Input() template: TemplateRef<{}>;
}
```

And then use it like that:

```html
<div appTest [template]="tmp">...</div>
<ng-template #tmp>
  Some content of the template
</ng-template>
```